# I want a custom attribute to be fired automatically without writing that on the web api method

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api2

I want a custom attribute to be fired automatically without writing that on the web api method.
What is the way I can achieve that?

Comment: What kind of attribute are you talking about? And welcome to StackOverflow by the way.

Comment: Hey thanks, I want to write an attribute for custom authentication.that if the user is not authenticated, don't allow the user to enter in the action  further and produce internal server error.

Comment: Aha - that is worth mentioning. @Nkosi's answer uses a filter attribute, but an authorization attribute would be more correct here. Always mention as much as the context as possible in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say for example you have an action filter attribute

```cs
public class MyApiActionFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute {
    //...
}
```

With that you can assign it to the class or action depending on how you want it to be used

```cs
public class MyApiController : ApiController {

    [MyApiActionFilter]
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This applies to this action only.

But, if you wanted it to be applied on all actions *(globally)* within the web API, you would need to add it to the configuration.

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyApiActionFilterAttribute ());
```

This is normally done at startup web configuring the web API.

Note that in doing the above, the filter will be applied to all requests.